# How to Change Sharepoint URL?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, redirect

I'm having an issue, I want to change (Edit) the SharePoint address (URL).

If that not possible  then

redirect the an old SharePoint site to a new SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give us more information about the question.

- is it host name based site collection?
- or is it just one site collection in the web app
- What is your URL pattern ( old & new).

If it is Web App Level.

- You need a new DNS which is pointing to proper WFE or Load Balacner
- Now you need update your AAM
- update the IIS binding if applicable

or
For host name based Site collection check this technet for changing it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same kind of requirement in my Old organization. So what we did is, we created a policy in load balancer, by which whenever the old url is getting accessed it redirects it to the New URL. You can try this.